# Nature of derivative for a function $u$ which is continuously differentiable on $\Bbb {R}$ satisfying $ u(y) \geq u(x)+u^{\prime}(x)(y-x), $

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following is true for every function $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $u$ is diffferentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and its derivative $u^{\prime}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ), and satisfies

$$
u(y) \geq u(x)+u^{\prime}(x)(y-x),
$$
for all $x ,y \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

(a) $u^{\prime}$ is nonnegative.

(b) $u$ attains a minimum at some $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(c) $u^{\prime}$ is nondecreasing.

(d) $u^{\prime}$ is nondecreasing.

I feel the question is misleading unless $x<y$, right? Neverthess, I got
$$
u(y) \geq u(x)+u^{\prime}(x)(y-x) \Rightarrow \frac{u(y)-u(x)}{y-x} \geq u'(x) \Rightarrow u'(x) \leq u'(\zeta),
$$ for some $\zeta > x$ by mean value theorem, how can it leads to the non-decreasing nature of $u'$?

Option (a) can be eliminated by considering $f(x)=-x^2$, right?

Any sort of help to find true options would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x, y \in \Bbb R$ we can add the two inequalities
$$
u(y) \geq u(x)+u'(x)(y-x) \\
u(x) \geq u(y)+u'(y)(x-y)
$$
and it follows that
$$
0 \ge (u'(x) - u'(y))(y-x)  \, .
$$
This shows that $y > x$ implies $u'(y) \ge u'(x)$, i.e. $u'$ is nondecreasing.

*Remark:* $u(y) \geq u(x)+u'(x)(y-x)$ for all $x, y$ means that the graph of $u$ lies above any of its tangent lines, that are exactly the *convex* functions.

The example $u(x) = e^{-x}$ shows that all other properties do not necessarily hold.

Comment: How nice it was..